# String replace with Regex

Tags: vb.net

What is the regular expression to replace sting in text with variable like

`{MERGEFIELD fieldname}`  in text with
`{DOCPROPERTY fieldname \* MERGEFORMAT}`

The fieldname is variable.

Comment: That's not very clear... can you just use [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: String.Replace would be the more obvious answer. If you can give a few more samples, you will receive more help

Answer (score 0):

```
   dim str as string = "{DOCPROPERTY fieldname \* MERGEFORMAT}"
   str = Regex.Replace(str, Regex.Escape(fieldname), "this is what you want to replace", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Note: you need to add on your string some identifier you want to replace. like for example, 
`"{DOCPROPERTY [fieldname_NAME] \* MERGEFORMAT}"` adding [ ] helps to proper identify. Here's the example.

```
   dim str as string = "Welcome, [name]"
   str = Regex.Replace(str, Regex.Escape("[name]"), "Jeff", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thanks zzzzz, but I don't think that will work for me, because the fieldname in text is always different like   {MERGEFIELD Company } , {MERGEFIELD Tel }, {MERGEFIELD Postcode }. etc. I need an expression to ignore part of string between start ( "{MERGEFIELD " ) and end (" }") part.

Answer (score 0):

I would first extract the field name, then format the new string:

```
Dim input = "{MERGEFIELD somefieldname}"
Dim fieldName = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=MERGEFIELD )\w+").Value
Dim newString = String.Format("{{DOCPROPERTY {0} \* MERGEFORMAT}}", fieldName)
'newString value is "{DOCPROPERTY somefieldname \* MERGEFORMAT}"
```